# Seeking Android Color Picker Library with Default Color Setting

Tags: android, color-picker

I'm seeking recommendations for an Android library or tool to implement a color picker, similar to the one depicted in the attached image. It's important for my project that the color picker supports setting a default color. I've been exploring different options, but haven't found one that meets all my criteria. Any suggestions for Android-compatible libraries or approaches would be greatly valued. Thank you in advance!

[image]